# Is there a Lucene Analyzer that removes all the non letters and converts all uppercase to lowercase?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, information-retrieval, analyzer

I am using Lucene 4.4 and I have a project to do. In that project all non-letters must be removed and all upper-case letters must be converted to lower-case. 
I know that there is an analyzer for removing non-letters.

But is there an analyzer in Lucene to both removes all non-letters and converts all upper-cases to lower-case?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes, there is an analyzer that does that.  [`SimpleAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/SimpleAnalyzer.html).

---

The following does (almost) exactly the same thing:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new LetterTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44, reader);
    TokenStream filter = new LowercaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, source);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```

When you have very specific requirements for an Analyzer, often you'll need to design your own by chaining a Tokenizer and some Filters like this, and as shown in the [`Analyzer` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html)
[`LetterTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LetterTokenizer.html) defines a token as a maximal string of adjacent letters, and [`LowercaseFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LowerCaseFilter.html) does what it says on the tin.

This is a fairly common combination, so there is also [LowercaseTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseTokenizer.html) which does the job of both LowercaseFilter and LetterTokenizer in one step, and thus provides a performance advantage.  `LowercaseTokenizer` is what is actually used by `SimpleAnalyzer`

Comment: I am just curious. Why did you say 'almost exactly' for the analyzer that you provided?

Comment: @yns For the reason in the last paragraph.  The results are exactly the same, but `SimpleAnalyzer` doesn't actually chain `LetterTokenizer` and `LowercaseFilter`, but rather it just uses `LowercaseTokenizer`, which performs a bit better.